# Slice a Pandas Dataframe based on the results of a function on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, series

I want to slice a dataframe using a condition based on a DateTime column's month, element by element:

```
Met_Monthly_DF = Metsite_DF.iloc[Metsite_DF['DateTime'].month == Month]
```

I get the error:

```
builtins.AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'
```

It works on an element by element basis if I do say:

```
Months = [DT.month for DT in Metsite_DF['DateTime'].tolist()]
```

How do I apply this condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

- for get datetimes like atributes need `dt` - here [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html)
- for [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) change `iloc` to `loc`

```
Met_Monthly_DF = Metsite_DF.loc[Metsite_DF['DateTime'].dt.month == Month]
```

Sample:

```
Metsite_DF = pd.DataFrame({'col':list('abcd'), 
                           'DateTime':pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=4, freq='16D')})
print (Metsite_DF)
    DateTime col
0 2017-01-01   a
1 2017-01-17   b
2 2017-02-02   c
3 2017-02-18   d

Month = 2
Met_Monthly_DF = Metsite_DF.loc[Metsite_DF['DateTime'].dt.month == Month]
print (Met_Monthly_DF)
    DateTime col
2 2017-02-02   c
3 2017-02-18   d
```

---

Or remove `iloc`, but then obviously need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
Met_Monthly_DF = Metsite_DF[Metsite_DF['DateTime'].dt.month == Month].copy()
```

If you modify values in `Met_Monthly_DF` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`Metsite_DF`), and that Pandas does warning.

```
Month = 2
Met_Monthly_DF = Metsite_DF[Metsite_DF['DateTime'].dt.month == Month]
#filter dataframe is modified - e.g. added new column for years
Met_Monthly_DF['new'] = Met_Monthly_DF['DateTime'].dt.year
print (Met_Monthly_DF)
    DateTime col   new
2 2017-02-02   c  2017
3 2017-02-18   d  2017
```

> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: 
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

---

```
Month = 2
Met_Monthly_DF = Metsite_DF[Metsite_DF['DateTime'].dt.month == Month].copy()

Met_Monthly_DF['new'] = Met_Monthly_DF['DateTime'].dt.year
print (Met_Monthly_DF)
    DateTime col   new
2 2017-02-02   c  2017
3 2017-02-18   d  2017
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael! As long as Month is an integer, your solution works a treat!