# How to transform column values of a dataframe to another dataframe with different indexes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes with equal number of rows.

```
df_a:

index   Id   X   Y
1       10   x1  - 
2       20   x2  -

-----------

df_b:

index   PostId   Text   
3       10       abcd
4       20       efg
```

Now how can I transform values of `df_b['Text']` to `df_a['Y']`. resulting this:

```
df_a:

index   Id   X   Y
1       10   x1  abcd
2       20   x2  efg
```

Note that indexes of mentioned dataframes are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the same number of rows, you can assign numpy array:

```
df_a['Y'] = df_b['Text'].to_numpy()
```

Older pandas versions:

```
df_a['Y'] = df_b['Text'].values
```

---

If want to map or merge be free to use some of solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53010406).

Comment: Thank you for always sharing knowledge :)

Comment: this is trivial

Comment: @jezrael there is a warning happening: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @AliKhatami - How is created `df_a` and `df_b` ?

Comment: @AliKhatami - Maybe is necessary `copy` like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113905/slice-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-the-results-of-a-function-on-a-column/48113923#48113923) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747589/copying-a-column-from-one-dataframe-to-another-gives-nan-values

Comment: @AliKhatami - Can you edit question with your full code?

Comment: @ansev - thank you, I cannot close, because reopend

Comment: @ansev - because I wait for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60093789/how-to-transform-column-values-of-a-dataframe-to-another-dataframe-with-differen/60093837?noredirect=1#comment106283358_60093837) :(

Comment: @jezrael sorry for my mistake, at first it worked but with a warning and not an error. So this answer solved my question. My question is not similar to the mentioned questions, because they are considering changing indexes and that is what I didn't want to do. Thanks again.